# how to pass data to controller as parameter with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I want to pass Array to Controller but I can't give correct URL 
when Click submit 404 error

my route

```
Route::post('store/{data}','DataController@store');
```

function

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
        dd($request);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,

    ]);

}
```

Ajax

```
     $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:"/store/"+arr,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
            },
            data:arr,
            success:function(response){
            alert('successful')                }
        });
```

and error

```
    POST http://localhost:8000/store%7Bname,number,number,address,work,$2y$10$Nl28n1pWCEaHxiHlcG.Y1On2DOdtXluHP0OvN5ih.Bvdfp/Issco2%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your route , the ajax call should be like this :

```
   $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url:"/data/"+arr . . .
```

or you can change your route for your ajax to work :

```
Route::post('store/{data}','DataController@store');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
There is no need for {data}
```

The ajax should be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:"/store/",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
        },
        data:arr,
        success:function(response){
        alert('successful')                }
    });
```

Comment: I change route to  Route::post('store', 'DataController@store');
dont have error but dd still does not work

Comment: You need to create an alias in apache vhosts for your laravel instance, because it will mingle with your other applications in your apache server.

Comment: can u suggest link or tell how to do this ?

Comment: here is my conf for vhost:        `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "dir_path/public"
    ServerName your-url.dev

    <Directory "dir_path/public">
        ServerSignature Off
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

try with 
Route::get('store/{data}','DataController@store');

and change ajax method to GET

Answer (score 0):

The $request variable is always available in a controller method. When you add an url parameter, you should also define it as a function parameter ($data)

```
public function store(Request $request, $data)
{
    dd($data);
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,

    ]);
}
```

Comment: how can I check if it goes to store method ?

Comment: What's the url to your laravel application?